# ListView element chooser from the design page

Tags: android

I came across a design [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) which contains an image of scrollable value chooser("Text message limit") - somewhat similar to a Listview component. Does this component exist ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) which is available at API level 11 (Android 3.0). But you can get it
from [android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/)(supported API level 7) library developed by Simon Vig Therkildsen. You only add it to your dialog.

Here is screenshot ![image]

Comment: is it possible to provide string instead of just numbers ?

Comment: I think its name already told. If you want text you can try see source code of time-picker.

Answer (score 2):

There is a view like that. You can access view from this link :

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/